# How to sign a string using RSA-SH512 (or RSA-SH256) and the private key of the signing certificate in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql, rsa, digital-signature

In Oracle pl/sql I need to sign a string using RSA-SHA512 or RSA-SHA256 with the private key of a certificate (this is a requirement for a webservice).

I found the DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT function with parameters src , typ and key
src will be equal to the string (converted to raw)
key will be the private key of my certificate (converted to raw).

But what should be the value of the key parameter to encrypt in RSA-SHA512 or RSA-SHA256?
Possible values are for example dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes and dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 but i see nothing like RSA-SHA.

Is this possible with DBMS_CRYPTO or are there any other options available in pl/sql?

Comment: I see a commercial package called ORA_RSA. Beware that this library seems to do a lot correctly, but I don't see **any** security analysis of it, nor any security claims when it comes to e.g. side channel attacks (!). In other words, I'd not use it on a machine that shares hardware with 3rd party software or which provides a high speed connection to untrusted machines.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL does not perform digital signatures natively. You will need a commercial package like DBSign to get that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a Java Class with this functionality and loading it in the oracle database. Then you create a plsql package that calls the java method.

Sounds complicated but it's actually not that hard and works well as this can be done with JDK internals.

Here is an example:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/calling-Java-from-PL-SQL.html#GUID-499ABE6B-4391-43C8-A527-74A6C7B0A0FF